# Using "module":" ES2020" instead of commonJS in nodejs project

Tags: node.js, typescript, tsconfig

is it possible to use ES2020 in tsconfig instead of coomonjs in nodejs project. Because when I use commonjs typescript when compiled generates a lot of javascript.

Answer (score 0):

`ES2020` and `commonjs` pertain to different things when configuring your `tsconfig.json`

`ES2020` will go in the [`lib`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#individual-library-components) array. It refers to *which language features to include*.

`commonjs` will go in the [`module`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#module) property. This refers to which module system you are using (ie. are you using `require` and `module.exports` syntax (commonjs), or `import` and `export` syntax (esm)?).

Comment: is it okay to use import export with nodejs ??

Comment: @HoucemEddine That's a whole other conversation that can't be addressed in a comment. Suggest you research javascript module systems.  Short answer is that historically nodejs has not supported import/export syntax, so people transpirled to commonjs